# Docker VOLUME command inside Dockerfile not working as expected

Tags: docker, docker-volume

```
FROM ubuntu:15.04
RUN mkdir -p /app/tina
RUN touch /app/tina/foo.txt
RUN echo "testing tina" > /app/tina/foo.txt
VOLUME /app/tina
CMD sh
```

As per Docker guide

> This Dockerfile results in an image that causes docker run to create a
>   new mount point at /app/tina and copy the foo.txt file into the newly
>   created volume

but when I do

```
docker run --rm -it -v /tmp/foo:/app/tina imagename sh
ls /app/tina/
```

I can't find foo.txt inside it.

Comment: have you created the docker image ? create a docker image first and run image. make sure you have files in this folder /tmp/foo?

Comment: Try placing the `RUN touch...` instruction after the `VOLUME` instruction?

Comment: @JinnaBalu yes I have created image and then pop a container from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that attaching an external directory as a volume using `-v` actually performs a bind mount: `/tmp/foo` directory is mounted to the `/app/tina` directory of the container.

In Linux, when you mount something, all files which were previously seen in the mount point (`/app/tina` in your case) become invisible. So, when you mount `/tmp/foo` (empty directory) to `/app/tina` (which contains `foo.txt`), the `foo.txt` file becomes invisible and you see the contents of `/tmp/foo` in the `/app/tina` directory, i.e. **nothing**.

You may ensure that you will see `foo.txt` in `/app/tina` when you will unmount `tmp/foo` from it:

```
root@84d8cfad500a:/# ls /app/tina
root@84d8cfad500a:/# umount /app/tina
root@84d8cfad500a:/# ls /app/tina
foo.txt
```

However, this would work only in the privileged (`docker run --privileged`) container (otherwise you will not be able to unmount `/app/tina`).

Comment: yes that make sense . So is it possible to have content copied to bind mount from container when its initiated by docker run ?

Comment: You can't do that with usual bind mounts. However, there is an option (proposed by @vladmihaisima in another post) to use docker volumes. With this option, Docker performs such a copy (from the container to the volume) on the container creation.

Answer (score 2):

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume

> The VOLUME instruction creates a mount point with the specified name and marks it as holding externally mounted volumes from native
>   host or other containers.

You are using /tmp/foo which is a directory, not a volume. Try:

```
docker volume create my-vol
docker run --rm -it -v my-vol:/app/tina imagename ls /app/tina/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your files are hidden. This is simply how mounts work. If I were to plug in a flash drive and mount it to `~/someDirectory`, then anything in `~/someDirectory` would be masked by the files available in the new mount. The volumes feature in docker works the same way.

You can avoid this behavior if you create `entrypoint.sh` and put these lines into entrypoint

```
RUN mkdir -p /app/tina
RUN touch /app/tina/foo.txt
RUN echo "testing tina" > /app/tina/foo.txt
```

when you create container (not image) docker creates volume and after it creates `foo.txt` and puts "testing tina" to the file.

Of course, don't forget to mention entrypoint in `Dockerfile`